# Как в секьюрити приложения лучше отделить запросы, для которых требуется авторизация от других?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

подключаю секьюрити к веб приложению - использую JWT, но не при всех запросах требуется авторизация, как отделить одни от других? Я тестирую правильность написания кода через постман, так вот при подключении зависимости spring security постман требует токен при каждом запросе, однако есть запросы где не требуется авторизация - как это реализовать? подскажите плиз[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так ведь ты в своей секьюрити конфигурации сам назначаешь, какие url'ы открыты, а какие требуют авторизации. Найди у себя в конфиге метод `configure(HttpSecurity http)` и там уже у этого `http` надо вызвать методы `antMatchers("твои_url").permitAll()`

Comment: посмотрите плиз - закомментил byTag, а он все равно без авторизации срабатывает

Comment: У тебя там указано `api/post/**`. Это значит, что все запросы, которые начинаются с этого uri будут доступны без авторизации. Поэтому убери эту строчку